# Sharepoint 2007 Usage Tracking Programmatic Access

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, usage-statistics

Does Sharepoint 2007 usage reporting track programmatic access to items in a document library? If not is there a non-intrusive and simple way to enable that functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sort answer: no. You'd need to write an itemeventreceiver that logs all programmatic access to items, but even that is only enough for when something is actually done to the item (so the eventreceiver gets triggered).

Any access logging beyond that (i.e. item is in say a resultset of an SPQuery) is all but impossible. Can I ask what exactly you'd like to achieve with tracking programmatic access? Maybe elaborating on that 'd lead to a more distinct answer.

Comment: A video player that loads it's videos from a document library as a means of providing analytics. Who's watching what, etc...